# labels for itemize in proposition

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, itemize

I have a Proposition which consists of an itemize with three claims, i.e.

```
\begin{prop}
\begin{itemize}
\item[(i)] ...
\item[(ii)] ...
\item[(iii)] ...
\end{itemize}
\end{prop}
```

I wish to insert labels and references in such a way to get things like

"...due to Proposition 4.1 (ii)..." or similar. How can I do? Should I use enumerate instead of itemize? Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

You could use the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) package, with which you could write:

```
\begin{Proposition}
   It is long known that
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman(*)]
   \item all numbers are interesting, but
   \item some numbers are more interesting than others.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{Proposition}
```

Comment: Good answer. However, you shouldn't reference my answer implicitly using "Or, ...". The order of answers with the same number of votes is random and having your one on top reads a little funny when it starts like that. ;-)

Comment: @Martin: I've fixed that. @Yossi: It would also be nice to see how references work with your solution.

Comment: `label=\roman(*)` did not work for me and threw an error. However, `label=(\roman*)` works just fine. Maybe this is due to a newer version.

Comment: The sol does not work well in beamer. Any idea why?

Comment: This answer doesn't answer what the question asked: how to automatically reference the items.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, an `enumerate` environment should be used here. After all it is a form of enumeration. You can change the item label by redefining `\labelenumi` (for first level, deeper levels are `\labelenumii`, `\labelenumiii` and `\labelenumiv`). You can then `\label` every `\item` you want to reference. The format of the reference text is given by `\theenumi` (`\theenumii`, ...).

I'm not sure if the `prop` environment you mention comes from a package, so I defined it here for the sake of completeness:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcounter{prop}[chapter]
\renewcommand*{\theprop}{\thechapter.\arabic{prop}}

\newenvironment{prop}{%
  \refstepcounter{prop}%
  \paragraph{Proposition~\theprop}%
  \renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\theprop\,(\roman{enumi})}%
  \renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}%
  \enumerate
}{%
  \endenumerate
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\begin{prop}
\item ...
\item\label{name} ...
\item ...
\end{prop}

...due to Proposition \ref{name} ...

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
\begin{Proposition}
  It is long known that
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman(*)]
    \item all numbers are interesting, but
    \item\label{itm:name} some numbers are more interesting than others.
  \end{enumerate}
 \label{prop:name}
\end{Proposition}
```

and then the cross-reference is:

```
  \ref{prop:name}.\ref{itm:name}.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Seems like this is duplicating an answer already give below.